# Merge multiple dictionaries in array and sum values

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
d = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Budd",
        "netWorth": "100000",
        "salary": "4700",
        "comment": "Cool"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tedd",
        "surname": "Walker",
        "netWorth": "400000",
        "salary": "8000",
        "comment": "Nice"
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Budd",
        "netWorth": "300000",
        "salary": "5000",
        "comment": "Pretty"
    }
]
```

I would like to sum `netWorth` and `salary` values when `name` and `surname` of dictionaries matches and do it with all items in the array of dictionaries.

Thing is that, the `comment` field is different and needs to be removed.
Is there any library out there to simplify this task?

Expected result after data manipulation:

```
d = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Budd",
        "netWorth": "400000",
        "salary": "9700"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tedd",
        "surname": "Walker",
        "netWorth": "400000",
        "salary": "8000"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried yourself? Where exactly are you stuck in your attempt to solve this?

Comment: Just in case you don't plan to use this in some production code, but are doing data analytics and planning to do more of it in the future - pandas! https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 2):

`dict` is a builtin, it`s bad taste to use its name as an identifier

```
In [8]: d = [
   ...:     {
   ...:         "name": "John",
   ...:         "surname": "Budd",
   ...:         "netWorth": "100000",
   ...:         "salary": "4700",
   ...:         "comment": "Cool"
   ...:     },
   ...:     {
   ...:         "name": "Tedd",
   ...:         "surname": "Walker",
   ...:         "netWorth": "400000",
   ...:         "salary": "8000",
   ...:         "comment": "Nice"
   ...:     },
   ...:     {
   ...:         "name": "John",
   ...:         "surname": "Budd",
   ...:         "netWorth": "300000",
   ...:         "salary": "5000",
   ...:         "comment": "Pretty"
   ...:     }
   ...: ]
```

We can use the `setdefault` method of regular dictionaries to sum the salary and the net worth

```
In [9]: w = {}
   ...: s = {}
   ...: for person in d:
   ...:     p = person['name'], person['surname']
   ...:     w[p] = w.setdefault(p, 0) + int(person['netWorth'])
   ...:     s[p] = s.setdefault(p, 0) + int(person['salary'])
   ...: print(w)
   ...: print(s)
{('John', 'Budd'): 400000, ('Tedd', 'Walker'): 400000}
{('John', 'Budd'): 9700, ('Tedd', 'Walker'): 8000}
```

Comment: I'd say it's more than just bad taste. Using a builtin as an identifier shadows the builtin and could lead to bugs later that are hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to access multiple keys with a dictionary's .get() method.  This can be leveraged to build a dictionary of totals for each pair of name/surname.  Then convert the counting dictionary back into a list of dictionaries:

```
names  = ('name','surname')       # keys to map for name/surname pairs
values = ('netWorth','salary')    # keys to map for totals

totals = dict()                   # totals per name/surname pairs
for p in d:                       # go through dictionaries
    for i,v in enumerate(values): # add multiple keys for name/surname pairs
        totals.setdefault((*map(p.get,names),),[0,0])[i] += int(p[v])

# convert back to a list of dictionaries
totals = [{k:w for k,w in zip(names+values,(*n,*v))} 
          for n,v in totals.items()]

print(totals)
[{'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Budd',   'netWorth': 400000, 'salary': 9700}, 
 {'name': 'Tedd', 'surname': 'Walker', 'netWorth': 400000, 'salary': 8000}]
```